# the best way to override a culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm looking for a way to override the Arabic culture and change its default calendar to the gregorian calendar instead of Um AlQura Calendar so that all of my apis return the gregorian calendar as date format when I send Arabic as accept-language.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.calendar

Comment: @stuartd setting this property has some extra logic, usually it throws exception that calendar is not valid for a culture

Comment: @YegorAndrosov yes, as covered in those docs and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.optionalcalendars?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you to do it on application level. That depends on the application you are running:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/set-current-culture

For a web application (since you are mentioning apis):

> Specify application level culture information in the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization
            culture="ja-JP"
            uiCulture="zh-HK"
        />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```